# decompose a real representation of a group $C_2\times C_2

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $\Phi$ be  a real representation of the group $C_2\times C_2=\{e,a\} \times \{e,b\}$ such as $ \Phi(a)=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -4 & 0\\6 & -5 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $ \Phi(b)=- E$

Decompose $ \Phi$ into a direct sum of irreps.

I know real irrreps of this group. They are:

- trivial representation $T$
- representation $A_1$, such as $A_1(a)=A_1(ab)=-1,$ $A_1(e)=A_1(b)=1$
- representation $A_2$, such as $A_2(b)=A_2(ab)=-1,$ $A_2(e)=A_2(a)=1$
- representation $A_3$, such as $A_3(a)=A_3(b)=-1,$ $A_3(e)=A_3(ab)=1$

I should find a matrix  $Q$ such as matrix $Q^{-1} \Phi(a) Q$ is  diagonal. Where the blocks along the diagonal are either $1$ or $-1.$ Then $Q^{-1} \Phi(B) Q$  is $\Phi^{-1}(A)$ (for T). But it is not diagonal!!!

I  get tripped up on this problem

I am not sure how to continue.
Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The question reduces to whether you can simultaneously diagonalize $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}5&-4\\6&-5\end{array}\right]\text{ and } \left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right]$$

To do this, you should find the eigenvalues of the first matrix.

---

Edit: more details

With some calculation, you can find that $\left[\begin{array}{c}2\\3\end{array}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right]$ are eigenvectors (of the first matrix) with eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$ respectively. With respect to the basis formed by these two vectors, the first matrix becomes  $\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]$; the second matrix is the same under this basis.

Comment: well, these matrices have the same eigenvalues ​​-1. So they  share a common one-dimensional subspace. I am not sure how to continue. sorry for my English

Comment: @nadia-liza Please see my edit above